# I need to create 3 rows in Student_Fee table when 1 row is inserted in Student table using trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

Following is the trigger

```
Create TRIGGER [dbo].[Student]
ON [dbo].[Student]
After INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    Insert Into Student_Fee([StudentID],[InstID],[PersonID],[FeeSubmiteTime],[FeeMsg],[Type])
    Select NULL,3,PersonID,getdate(),'Student submitted on','Student' from INSERTED
END
```

I need to create 3 rows in Student_Fee table when 1 row is inserted in Student table.First row in Student_fee must have StudentID Null and for other two rows student ID is filled obtained from previous table. Also, `Feemsg` should be different for the 3 rows. It is text and could be any value. And for type there are two types `Student` and `Admin` and the types are also not fixed. They can vary while inserting rows.
How can I do that by using trigger?

Comment: what `previous table` are you referring to ? Anyway, you can do another 2 `insert` statement or use `UNION ALL` to insert the additional 2 rows

Comment: You can either write 3 insert statement in your trigger or write 1 statement that joins to a numbers table 3 times to do this. But don't - I suggest you start over and get help with both your schema and your design. I cannot imagine any valid reason for using NULL as a value in StudentID or hardcoding 3 as InstID (which sounds like a foreign key to an Institution table).

Answer (score 0):

here you go :

```
CREATE TABLE Temp1abhari (
    id INT identity(1, 1)
    ,number INT
    );

CREATE TABLE Temp2abhari (
    id INT
    ,number INT
    );

CREATE TRIGGER TTemp1abhari ON Temp1abhari
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Temp2abhari
    VALUES (
        NULL
        ,1
        );

    INSERT INTO Temp2abhari
    SELECT ID
        ,2
    FROM Inserted;

    INSERT INTO Temp2abhari
    SELECT ID
        ,3
    FROM Inserted;
END
```